# How to change owner for docker socket in container (macOS, Intel Chip)

Tags: docker

I have a fresh install of `docker desktop` on my machine and I'm attempting to create a dev environment. Using `docker.io/library/wordpress:latest`

**However**, I'm having some **issues with user permissions**. From what I can see the documentation doesn't mention this issue for mac users, but does mention something for ubuntu users ([See Doc's](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#:%7E:text=The%20Docker%20daemon%20always%20runs,members%20of%20the%20docker%20group.)). The specific issue is as follows;

```
// Docker error msg...

chown: invalid group: 'root:docker'
WARNING: Could not change owner for docker socket in container : exit code 1
Docker socket permission set to allow in container docker

// My setup...

macOS BigSir 11.6.5(Intel Chip)
Docker Desktop 4.8.2
VSCode Version: 1.67.1
git version 2.36.1
```

**My Question:** How do I resolve this issue? I.e. What steps do I need to take?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated...

**Note:** I can see other questions floating around here on stack, but from what I can see they're mostly covering ubuntu users or quite old questions and answers.

**Note:** Added screenshots to demonstrate what I was doing when the error occurred.

**Step 1**
[image: docker create dev environment]

**Step 2**
[image: docker supply official image]

**Step 3** -- Error
[image: docker build log of official image]

Comment: What's the actual issue?  Do you have any of your own application source code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: There is no application, it's just a straight up install of Docker, and an attempt at building a dev environment on macOS, using `docker.io/library/wordpress:latest` nothing exists yet until the container is created, as I understand it.

Comment: What command are you running, and what error are you getting?  If you're running Docker Desktop, the socket will generally be owned by the current user and you don't need to do anything with group membership.

Comment: @DavidMaze no commands, not skilled enough with docker yet to use commands like a pro.  I've added screenshots showing what I'm doing, and how the error occurs. Hopefully this helps you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Most docker image in public registry is not designed to compatible with Docker Dev Environments (Beta).

According to documentation: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/dev-environments/specify/, specified docker image is required to have `docker` group and `vscode` user which already included to the group.

So we need to modify official docker image for your case to be working fine with docker dev environments and visual studio code.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM docker.io/library/wordpress:latest

# the next two commands are required based on documentation
# https://docs.docker.com/desktop/dev-environments/specify/
RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -m vscode \
  && groupadd docker \
  && usermod -aG docker vscode

USER vscode
```

Build our new docker image by running `docker build`, e.g:

```bash
docker build -t bickyeric/wordpress:dev-latest -f Dockerfile .
```

After that, you can update image tag from Step 2 of Question with our new image `bickyeric/wordpress:dev-latest`
[image]